# Starting database ... failed in MonetDB

Tags: sql, monetdb

I tried to start a DB after creating it in MonetDB, but I got this error:

starting database 'sf1'... FAILED
start: starting 'sf1' failed: database 'sf1' appears to shut itself down after starting, check monetdbd's logfile for possible hints

Do you have any idea?

Comment: hi, please provide much more detail..thanks!

Comment: Please also post the last lines of the log file (usually `merowingian.log` within the dbfarm directory.

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem. I ran an instruction from my log file:

```
/home/mirzadeh/tools/MonetDB/bin/mserver5 --dbpath=/home/mirzadeh/tools/MonetDB/var/monetdb5/my_farm/sf1 --set merovingian_uri=mapi:monetdb://n125:50000/sf1 --set mapi_open=false --set mapi_port=0 --set mapi_usock=/home/mirzadeh/tools/MonetDB/var/monetdb5/my_farm/sf1/.mapi.sock --set monet_vault_key=/home/mirzadeh/tools/MonetDB/var/monetdb5/my_farm/sf1/.vaultkey --set gdk_nr_threads=24 --set max_clients=64 --set sql_optimizer=default_pipe --set monet_daemon=yes
```

and got a fatal error regarding locale. I ran locale and see that it cannot set `LC_ALL`, and `LC_LANG`. I added these two inst in my bashrc file:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Then it works!